# Setting Content-Disposition header filename in iText java

Tags: java, pdf, header, content-disposition

I am getting the userid from here

```
 String struserid  = tempdb.getuserid();
```

This is how I am setting content disposition header.

```
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.pdf");
```

This will prompt to download an attachment with filename as 'sample.pdf'. But I need the filename like '123456_sample.pdf'

Note: 123456 is the value that I got from db and it is stored as string struserid

Comment: No one knows the answer????

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the strings? `"attachment; filename=" + struserid + "_sample.pdf"`

Comment: yes simple. Why cant you put it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + struserid + "_sample.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + struserid + "_sample.pdf");
```

works for me.

Comment: Can you explain, why it works for you? Some more information would be very usefull for future readers

Comment: There's no advantage. The field value is invalid.